# How to detach a div box according to window size and replace somewhere else

Tags: jquery

The initial structure of my html looks like this:

```
<div class="geniuses">
   <div class="one-first">       
   </div>

   <div class="one-second">
   </div>

   <div class="one-third">  
   </div><!-- one third-->
</div>
```

How can I detach the div with the class one-second and place it before the div with the class one-first?

At the moment my jquery looks like this:

```
$(window).resize(function resize(){
   if($(window).width() < 1070){
       $('.one-second').detach();
       $('.one-first').before($('.one-second'));
   }         
}).trigger('resize');
```

For now I can only detach, but I am struggling to put the content back where I want and also when I make the screen bigger than 1070 pixels, the div does not appear back.

[Hope you can help from the pen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/OWbWYK)

Answer (score 1):

After you `detach` the `div`, you can store it into a variable or a jQuery object, and attach it back (`appendTo`, `prependTo`).

Let's say this is our HTML -

```
<body>
    <div class="geniuses">
      <div class="one-first">A
      </div>

      <div class="one-second">P
      </div>

      <div class="one-third">Z
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function resize() {
      if ($(window).width() > 1070) {
        // if width is more the 1070px. tweek accordingly.
        var $p = $('.one-second').detach();
        $p.prependTo($('.one-first'));

      } else {
        // To put things back into place
        var $p = $('.one-second').detach();
        $p.appendTo($('.one-first'));

      }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The script was only working if I explicitly had to resize the page, but I added the triggering as you can see in my answer and it works just perfectly. 
Appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are detaching it never attaching is back. You creating a new `div` and using `.before()` to prepend string literal `.one-first` to it.

You need place target the element and use it. Note [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) accepts a element or HTML string to be inserted before the `selector`.

```
$(window).resize(function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1070) {
        $('.one-first').before($('.one-second'));
        //$('.one-second').insertBefore('.one-first');
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

As an alternatively [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) can also be used.

> The `.before()` and `.insertBefore()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With .before(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container before which the content is inserted. With `.insertBefore()`, on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted before the target container.

```js
$('.one-first').before($('.one-second'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="geniuses">
  <div class="one-first">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="one-second">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="one-third">
    3
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I just did as you showd but the result remain the same. Here my snippet: http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/OWbWYK. It only detaches but it never inserts the before function.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, Issue is with condition `$(window).width() < 1070` Just for validation use http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyVBWM?editors=1010 and see my code I have removed `('.one-second').detach();`

Answer (score 0):

Completing the response of @PEJK here is the answer

```
$(window).resize(function resize() {
   if ($(window).width() > 1070) {
      // if width is more the 1070px. tweek accordingly.
      var $p = $('.one-second').detach();
      $p.prependTo($('.one-first'));
   } else {
       // To put things back into place
       var $p = $('.one-second').detach();
       $p.appendTo($('.one-first'));
   }
}).trigger('resize');
```